# Trying to locate/identify a component

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, led-driver

I am trying to id the chip to the right:

[image: S2524 and surrounding components]

This is part of a PENTAIR GLoBrite Driver board PCBA 620244 which drives three pieces of 4-color LED. In its glory days it colored a pool, but the holster cracked and water entered.

The chip I am looking for is the S2425 seen on the right. I assume it is the LED driver chip. There are four of them, one for each color.

A google search revealed nothing. Mouser, Digikey lookups the same. Searched for markings but same thing.

I have so far come up quite empty, and hoping that someone here might have this info?

Comment: *There are 4 of them, one for each color* - and you are saying that you are showing us a photo of the most preserved one of them? The condition of this area and components around make me think this thing isn't going to work anymore.. so why do you need this component?

Comment: The image is S2524, but your text is S2425. Double check that you've been searching for the correct part.

Comment: I did search for 2524 and not as I wrote. Just another typo;-)
I am planning to redo the board. I got two out of 4 lights dead and can save quite a bit by building a new one. Plus it's a neat little project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a LED Driver corresponding to your component in a SOT-89-5 package :

SN3360GP05E from ISSI (Integrated Silicon Solution).
First line seems to be a traceability code, the second line is the part number code.

Here is a picture of it :

[image]

Comment: ISSI makes things other than memory chips‽